# Inline asm in c++ in vs __asm

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, compiler-errors, inline-assembly

```
char name[25];
int generated_int;

for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(name); i++)
{
    name[i] = (char)0;
}

cout << "Name: ";
cin >> name;

int nameLen = strlen(name);

__asm
{
    pusha;

    mov esi, &name //I got error here, I cant use "&". How to move name address to esi?
    mov ecx, nameLen
    mov ebx, 45

start:
    mov al, [esi]
    and eax, 0xFF
    mul ebx
    inc esi
    add edi, eax
    inc ebx
    dec ecx
    jnz start

    mov generated_serial, edi

    popa
}



cout << endl << "Serial: " << generated_serial << endl << endl;
```

I don't know how to get address of my chay array in asm block.
When I try to use "&" e.g. &name i get error while compiling:

```
error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'second operand'; found 'AND'
```

UPDATE:

mov esi, name gives me this compile error: C2443: operand size conflict

UPDATE 2:
lea is working fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `lea` instruction, which loads the effective address of some symbol into a register. The following instruction will store the address of `name` in `esi`.

```
lea esi, name
```

Comment: mov esi, name gives me this compile error: C2443: operand size conflict

Answer (score 4):

`name` is already (or rather decays to) a pointer. Just use `mov esi, name`.

Comment: mov esi, name gives me this compile error: C2443: operand size conflict

Comment: change the operand size equal to esi register. (casting before _asm)

Answer (score 1):

```
move esi, name
```

already is the address of name. If you wanted the content (name[0]) you would use

```
move esi, [name]
```

Comment: mov esi, name gives me this compile error: C2443: operand size conflict

Comment: @Hooch - Probably because it is a char array. The assembler really shouldn't care about the type, it is just an address.

Answer (score 1):

`lea` is what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[25];
    char* fmt = "%p\n";

    __asm {
        lea eax,name
        push eax
        mov eax,fmt
        push fmt
        call printf
    }
    return 0;
}
```